# Renamed a method in codeigniter's controller. How do I redirect using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

After looking in a lot places, finally posting it here.

I have rename a method in codeigniter's controller from classDetails to class-details.

I am using the following code in .htaccess but it did not work

```
RewriteRule ^classDetails/(.*)$ class-details/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have also tried this code in /application/config/routes.php

```
$route['classDetails'] = 'class-details';
```

I have also tried

```
$routes['classDetails'] = 'class-details';
```

I have even tried using _remap() in codeigniter as follows

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array()){
switch ($method){
    case 'classDetails':$method='class_details'; break;
};

if (method_exists($this, $method))
{
    return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
}
show_404();
}
```

No matter what I do it goes to 404 page

Where am I doing it wrong?

[EDIT]

my method name is class_details and I am overwriting that in the url using a custom core class called MY_Router.php

Comment: First of all you are not using correct convention for a method name you can use class-details as method name you can use only all small case or camel case for method name otherwise it will never gonna work. you can give your method name as classDetails and in route you have to write something like this

$routes['class-details'] = '<controllerName>/classDetails';

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not using correct convention for a method name you can use class-details as method name you can use only all small case or camel case for method name otherwise it will never gonna work. you can give your method name as classDetails and in route you have to write something like this

```
 $routes['class-details'] = '<controllerName>/classDetails';
```